# How to prevent a TextArea that resizes from overflowing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm working to create a TextArea that is horizontally and vertically centered in the page. Given that I need the TextArea to be vertically centered, I can't have the textarea be 100w and 100h, I need it to start with a small height and then grow as the user types. I also need a click capturer so if the user clicks the area surrounding the textarea, the textarea focuses. (the gray bkg is just for debugging purposes)

I have a demo on CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQbvxa

```js
autosize(document.getElementById("note"));

$( ".textAreaClickCapturer" ).mouseup(function() {
  $( "#note" ).focus();
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-body.fullScreen {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0!important;
  align-items: normal;
  justify-content: normal;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

form .textAreaClickCapturer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center
}

form .field {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
  clear: both;
  max-height: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-body fullScreen ">
  <form action="/">
    <div class="textAreaClickCapturer" role="presentation">
      <div class="field">
        <textarea id="note" placeholder="Say something..." rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When you type in multiple lines, the TextArea does grow nicely but eventually, the TextArea grows pasts the size of the screen causing it to break.

How can I get the TextArea are to grow where the TextArea doesn't go behind the page and break but has a working overflow to handle lots of text?

Desired Initial Experience

[image: Desired Initial Experience]

Broken UI, when the textarea grows past the surrounding div.

[image: bad broken ui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason is that when using `align-items: center` and/or `justify-content: center`, the element overflow its parent both at, in this case, top/bottom.

To solve that, one need to use auto margin's instead, and with that be able to control the alignment both vertical and horizontal, top/bottom, left/right, etc.

You also had a lot of `height: 100%` in your code (which I cleaned up), and combined with Flexbox, that cause more issues, so instead use Flexbox's own properties, e.g. here `flex: 1` on flex column items, that will fill the parent's height.

*Also added `min-height: 0` so Firefox play along.*

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQNePy)

Stack snippet

```js
autosize(document.getElementById("note"));

$( ".textAreaClickCapturer" ).mouseup(function() {
  $( "#note" ).focus();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.page-body.fullScreen {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #efefef;
  min-height: 0;
}

form {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

form .textAreaClickCapturer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

form .field {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  padding: 24px;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-body fullScreen ">
  <form action="/">
    <div class="textAreaClickCapturer" role="presentation">
      <div class="field">
        <textarea id="note" placeholder="Say something..." rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use  `max-width` and `max-height`:

```
textarea {
  ...
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

**Update**

I simplified both HTML and CSS, snippet:

```js
autosize(document.getElementById("note"));
$(".textAreaClickCapturer").mouseup(function() {
  $("#note").focus();
});
```

```css
html, body, form {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #efefef;
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /*center vertically*/
  padding: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>

<form class="textAreaClickCapturer" action="/">
  <textarea id="note" placeholder="Say something..." rows="3"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following in your pen:

In the textarea selector in CSS, add:

`max-height: 90%;
 overflow: auto;`

This gives you a scrollbar if the content entered exceeds the max height, and the max-height is controlled by the containing div's size.

Answer (score 0):

Add a max height, like the others have said, me personally I prefer to use vh when relating to height in your situation. So in your pen it would just be:

```
textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  max-height:50vh;
}
```

and you're squared away. Your vertical overflow is scrolling by default so there really isn't any more you have to do.