# How to add a class that moves the TextArea to the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following snippet below that vertically aligns a TextArea as desired.

How can I add a class somewhere in the code that aligns the textarea to the top of the page, vs the current vertically aligned center positioning? I need both top or center alignment which is why I'm asking for a class that can be added to change the textarea position.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen .textAreaClickCapturer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-Size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="ui small form full-screen">
  <div class="textAreaClickCapturer">
  <textarea placeholder="Hi..." style="height: 132px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the three nested flexboxes? Is that necessary for some other functionality not included here?

Comment: Hi, yes it is, I need the textarea to be vertically aligned so the textarea placeholder is horizonally and vertically centered... That means the area outside of the textarea looks like a textarea to the user so I can capture the user's mouse click and then refocus on the textarea.

Comment: you cant center something that has 100% width. (your textarea), your welcome :D

Comment: I don't want to change the text, I want the textarea to be positioned at the top of the page, not in the middle like current

Comment: What I mean is, why not just one flexbox? [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/zs0o6y8j/).

Comment: I helped with your other question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674422/483779 you can change it to `align-items: flex-start;` for not centering the textarea vertically. With the current question remove `margin: auto;` from the textarea.

Comment: @Stickers thank you, that was the hiccup... If you answer, I'll mark as selected. Thanks

Comment: @AnApprentice If you're happy with any of the existing answers feel free to accept, I still don't get what's the need of using of nested flexbox though.

Comment: As the answer to this is given in your previous question's accepted answer, I decided to close this as a duplicate. To also make that more clear, I made a minor update of my answer's 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align-items: flex-start` in a class `.align-top`. So when you insert the `.align-top` to your form class the items will be top aligned.

```
form.ui.form.full-screen.align-top {
 align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}
form.ui.form.full-screen.align-top {
 align-items: flex-start;
}
form.ui.form.full-screen .textAreaClickCapturer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-Size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="ui small form full-screen align-top">
  <div class="textAreaClickCapturer">
  <textarea placeholder="Hi..." style="height: 132px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `align-self:flex-start;`

Source [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen .textAreaClickCapturer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-height: 0;
  align-self:flex-start;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-Size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="ui small form full-screen">
  <div class="textAreaClickCapturer">
  <textarea placeholder="Hi..." style="height: 132px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding `position: absolute` has done the trick.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen .textAreaClickCapturer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

form.ui.form.full-screen textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-Size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="ui small form full-screen">
  <div class="textAreaClickCapturer">
    <textarea placeholder="Hi..." style="height: 132px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: there isn't a way to do it with flexbox?

Comment: yes there is, take a look at my answer